# Is there a way to monitor what bitcoin-qt is doing on a mac os x?

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, mac

Using 0.6.6.2 on a mac mini; has been running for 56 hours now, still not fully synchronised; is there a way to monitor whether the program is actually doing something or just stuck? would the 0.8.x be faster?

Comment: Ah, one is supposed to hover the cursor around the spinning wheel in the lower right corner, then a notification appears ...

Answer (score 1):

It takes forever and a day to have Bitcoin-Qt sync up with the Blockchain for the first time. Also try executing "netstat -n -P TCP | grep '.8333'" in a terminal window to see if you have eight concurrent socket connections into the Bitcoin network.

Comment: Yep. it's usually much, much faster to ask for the block-chain to be delivered to you on a DVD, or to download it - there are some torrents for it. Of course, theoretically you could be receiving a tampered blockchain, or a virus/trojan, etc. In practice, it's usually safe

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window and enter this command:

```
tail -f ~/Library/Application\ Support/Bitcoin/debug.log
```

You will get a scrolling log of all the detailed activity of bitcoin-qt.

Answer (score 0):

Run bitcoin-qt from command line and redirect the error and the standard output to a file :

```
bitcoin-qt 2>&1 /path/to/your/log/file
```

check your log file to find what's going on ..

You can see the log file in real time on screen by typing :

```
tail -f /path/to/your/log/file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also go to Help -> Debug Window to see if you have active Connections and if the blocks are moving.